# how to make multiple django websites share one user database to authenticate?

Tags: database, django

I am planing to make 2 or 3 websites using django. Each website has its own subject. For example : site A is ecomercial website and site B is a forum.

And I hope those website user can share one account, it means, one account, can login those website.

It means, he can create an account in the forum, and them shopping in that website shop. Using the same user name and passworkds etc.

And those 2 or 3 website may not in same host, I may need remote database for this authenticate.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 4):

The Django docs cover having multiple database configured [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example), using the same 'auth_db' and AuthRouter in multiple projects should work:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'auth_db': {
        'NAME': 'auth_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PASSWORD': 'swordfish',
    },

}


class AuthRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
        database.
        """
        if db == 'auth_db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'auth'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return False
        return None
```

Comment: how about i set a restful api in one website ,then other websites send the authentication info to this api to check the user login info? in this way ,i do not need modify the database ,and can be usefull in remote website .one master website .more guest websites.just keep the guest website IP in the master website check list .any other request from other IP ,will ignore .

Comment: You shouldn't have to modify any database, auth_db can be the default DB from another Django project.

Comment: also the DB can be remote as well, just update the HOST setting to the remote host/ip of your database installation.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this, is just like how StackExchange does it; by creating your own openid provider.

Its very easy with [python-openid](https://github.com/openid/python-openid), which provides a [sample server](https://github.com/openid/python-openid/blob/master/examples/server.py) as part of its documentation.

Once you have it setup, use [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) to integrate with openid.

Comment: This isn't answering the question that was asked, although I agree that this is a good alternative to what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution without using the same DB as auth-db.

This procedure is based on CAS (Central Authentication Service) protocol which supports SSO (Single Sign-On) and SLO (Single Logout) for Django and Flask frameworks:

1. A CAS-Client is needed so I used the new generation of Django-CAS called [django-cas-ng package](https://github.com/django-cas-ng/django-cas-ng) and [here is its configuration](https://djangocas.dev/blog/django-cas-ng-example-project/) to make your own client. (Also, here is a [pre-configured client repo](https://github.com/django-cas-ng/example))
2. A CAS-Server is needed so I used a [pre-configured repo](https://github.com/django-cas-ng/demo-cas-server).

---

[**NOTE**]:

- It supports *Django 1.11, 2.x, and 3.x*